# setOnItemClickedListener not working (gridview)

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview in my code and a custom adapter. I'm trying to set a setOnItemClickedListener but i have no return.

Can someone help me understand why my setOnItemClickListener does not work?

Thank you!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.com.m.bpuzzle.data.Card;
import br.com.m.bpuzzle.data.ImageLevel;
import br.com.m.bpuzzle.data.PuzzleAdapter;
import br.com.m.bpuzzle.util.Constantes;

public class BPuzzleActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView puzzle;
    private ImageLevel puzzleLevel;
    private PuzzleAdapter adapter;
    private static BPuzzleActivity context;
    private static ArrayList<Card> itens;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        context = this;
        setupPuzzle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        context.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim__fadeout, R.anim.anim__fadein);
    }

    private void setupPuzzle() {
        Log.i(Constantes.APPTAG, "Setup puzzle");

        puzzleLevel = new ImageLevel(8, ImageLevel.LEVEL_ANIMALS);
        itens = puzzleLevel.getListElements();

        adapter = new PuzzleAdapter(itens, context);

        puzzle = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.puzzle);
        puzzle.setAdapter(adapter);
        puzzle.setClickable(true);

        puzzle.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemGridViewClickListener());
    }

    private static class ItemGridViewClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Card item = itens.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Card: " + item.getCardID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

My layout (item for gridview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Adapter

```
public class PuzzleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Card> puzzleLevel;
    public static Context context;

    public PuzzleAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Card> puzzleData) {
        context = ctx;
        puzzleLevel = puzzleData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.puzzleLevel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Card getItem(int position) {
        return puzzleLevel.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageButton image;
        if (convertView == null) {
            image = new ImageButton(context);
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid__item, null);
        } else {
            image = (ImageButton) convertView;
        }

        image.setImageResource(Constantes.HIDECARD_RESOURCE);
        image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
        image.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        return image;
    }

}
```

**UPDATED**

I changed my layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/card" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works. For some reason when I put an ImageButton in my "custom adapter" the 'click' does not work.

Thank you all!

Comment: Could you describe "does not work"? For starters, does it crash? Do you see the Toast?

Comment: The toast does not appear. no error is displayed (in logcat)

Comment: Please post PuzzleAdapter, since this works fine with a ArrayAdapter<String>.

Comment: here is the code of my adapter....

Comment: I see a issue with your convertview code. Comment out the if (convertView==null) with else code (since its only a performance workaround). And test it out.

Comment: Ok, @Siddharth . I changed the code to:
 
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid__item, null);
  ImageButton image = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
  image.setImageResource(Constantes.HIDECARD_RESOURCE);
  image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
  image.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  return convertView;
 }

Comment: Now what is the behavior ? Same issue ? How ever silly it may sound, you do need to share the results after the change too for clarity in communication.

Comment: @Siddharth , same issue. Nothing happens when i click in the gridview item.

Comment: Ok got it, You have setItemOnListener on the gridview, and not on the grid view item.

Comment: i`m sorry..can you give me an example?

Comment: Google it, I am sure you will get a lot there.

Comment: @Siddharth I disagree, you can apply an OnItemSelectedListener to every grid item by applying it to the GridView itself.

Comment: @Siddharth i will not put the clicklistener inside my adapter... (is that what you are saying?). I think that's not a good option...

Comment: Try it, if it works you know the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in my case

```
        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(myImages, myViews));
        sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(EquipmentViews.this, VIRDemo.class);
                i.putExtra("EquipmentId", equipmentIds[position]);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Adapter class

```
/**
 * Adapter for our image files.
 */
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int[] myRemoteImages;
    private String[] myRemoteViews;

    public ImageAdapter(int[] myimages, String[] myviews) {
        myRemoteImages = myimages;
        myRemoteViews = myviews;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.myRemoteImages.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.imageitem, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            tv.setText(myRemoteViews[position]);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            iv.setImageResource(myRemoteImages[position]);

        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Nothing happens... I changed my code, put all inside the adapter...maybe isn't the best way, but the only way that works. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Hey! I found... i changed my imagebutton to a imageview (inside a linearview) and ....worked! thankss!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the android:clickable="true" in your layout.
When you mark the ImageButton clickable and then click on your GridView item, the controller looks for a click handler for the ImageButton and not the GridView item. 
As a result, your OnItemClick method is never called. When you changed your layout, you did not have clickable=true.

Answer (score 1):

Never working with gridview but I usually set up my adapter like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageButton image;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView  = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid__item, null);
    }

    image = (ImageButton)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(Constantes.HIDECARD_RESOURCE);
    image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
    image.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i`m using android 2.3.3 .

Comment: Try remove `puzzle.setClickable(true);`. I don't think it needed.

Comment: i changed my code..but.. i got the same "error". Nothing happens when i click in my gridview item.

Comment: Debug your code. Put a breakpoint at `Card item = itens.get(position);` to see can it get the item here.

Comment: So where does it stop? Does it run to `puzzle.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemGridViewClickListener());`